# Is it possible to modify Webpack module execution order via a loader or plugin?

Tags: javascript, webpack

My company is using Webpack for a large project with thousands of modules. We use classes extensively, and because classes are not hoisted in ES6, recursive dependency issues occur frequently.

Here’s a simplified scenario:

```
// a.js ////
import {B} from './b';

export class A {
  isB(b) {
    return b instanceof B;
  }
}

// b.js ////
import {A} from './a';
export class B extends A {}

// index.js ////
import './a';
```

See a [running example](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KoKMDQF1htf9Z4fg4B_) of the problem.

In this scenario, the desired execution order is `b > a > index`, because `b` has a static dependency on `a` , while `a` can defer evaluating `b`. Naturally, however, Webpack doesn't know this (nor should it, per the spec).

I’d like to write a Webpack plugin and/or loader that lets me do the following:

```
import {B} from 'defer!./b';
```

The `defer` loader would cause `a`'s dependency on `b` to be added to the dependency graph, but to be ignored for the purposes of ordering module execution.

Is there an API that plugins or loaders to can access to accomplish this? I didn't see anything in the docs. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.